# How does one cancel text-align: justify for Chinese text (or any text that doesn't use space characters)?

Tags: html, css, chinese-locale

In order to prevent certain phrases from being spaced apart in justified text, one simply needs to use a `&nbsp;` between the words instead of a normal space. But how can this concept be carried over to Chinese text? "Words" ("characters") that have no space character between them are automatically spaced apart in a justified paragraph. See https://jsfiddle.net/oak5wxoz/2/

The obvious solution (using a `&zwj;`) doesn't work. (Though it did seem to have an effect on the text - just not the desired effect; see the very first line.)

In order to see the effect, you may need to resize the jsfiddle frame. An image of the result is attached.

```
<P CLASS="justified">Unimaginatively latin <SPAN CLASS="unjustify">中&zwj;文</SPAN></P>
```

and

```
.justified
{text-align:justify}
.unjustify
{text-align:left}
```

[image]

What I am asking is how can one cancel text-justify in a `<SPAN>` of Chinese text? This question is somewhat related to, but not at all a duplicate of, any question about cancelling text-align: justify in a `<SPAN>` of text of any language that ordinarily uses space characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now I feel foolish for posting the question, but the answer was partially there, in the solution that I had tried.

`text-align` cannot apply to inline elements, so `display: inline-block` needs to be applied to the span, and there it is.

updated: https://jsfiddle.net/oak5wxoz/3/